# You Do Not have Current iOS Development Certificate

Tags: ios, iphone

My paid Developer ID Showing this Erro [image]

Xcode 7

Comment: Once you check your Itunes developer account, your checked on that in-app purchase, Or else you delete old certificate of this particular app and create new provision certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable in-app purchases from Capabilities.

1. Click on workSpace (your project name) from the left side navigator.
2. Select your project from targets.
3. Select capabilities (you will find next to General settings in newest Xcode)
4. Turn the switch on corresponding to in-app purchases.

Try this may help.